# Is there a way to prevent a python window from being seen when opened?

Tags: python, windows

So I want to make a Python file that runs all the code within, but the window is invisible. So the user won't see the window in the task bar, or really anywhere on his screen.

How would I do something like that?

Comment: Which window? What are you talking about? Please provide coherent and sufficient information.

Comment: Why do you want to hide a process from me, the end user, on my PC?

Answer (score 4):

To make a script not open the terminal window change the extension of your script to `.pyw`  which will cause the script to be executed by `pythonw.exe` by default. This suppresses the terminal window on startup.

If you would like all scripts to open like this you should read up on [Executing Scripts](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#executing-scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want to use `start pythonw.exe`